# change integer number to wstring in c++

Tags: c++, integer, wstring

I have the following code, which I am trying ot change an integer number to wstring then I can pass it to a text file. but the problm is that when it reached to the _itow_s(vec, img_stamp, 10); line it change the number to a negative number. 
any body know what is the problem?

```
wchar_t img_stamp[64];
   while(c<_timeStamp.size()){      
        vec=_timeStamp.at(c);
        _itow_s(vec, img_stamp, 10);    
        _data +=std::wstring(img_stamp);
        _data +=std::wstring(L"\r\n");
        c++;
    }


    HANDLE hFile; 
    DWORD wmWritten;    
    hFile = CreateFile( "D:\\test\\testing.txt" ,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL); 
    if(hFile!=NULL){

        DWORD len=sizeof(_data);
        WriteFile(hFile, _data.c_str(), _data.size() * 2, &wmWritten, NULL);
    }   
    CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a `wstringstream`?

```
wstringstream ws;
for (...) { // some loop
  ws << myint << ", ";
}
//now, you can use ws.str() to extract a wstring from the stream
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but the problem is that if I dont use wstring, I can add the data to the txt file throguh WriteFile

Comment: But that does give you a `wstring`! `ws.str()` gives you the `wstring` contained in the stream. (I've edited the code to make that clear.)

Comment: This will solve the problem.  +1  Of course, using `+=` for string concatenation when you already have a `wstringstream` is kinda silly.  Use the stream to collect *everything*, then convert to string once at the end.

Answer (score 3):

C++11 added a function called '[std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)()' which converts a number, float, or long long to a std::string. There is also a related set of functions for wstrings: [std::to_wstring](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring)().